# Converting Shading Nodes

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, geometry-nodes

I need to export a model that uses both geometry nodes and shading nodes.

I can figure out how to make the sprinkles a part of the mesh with realize instance, but they lose all their varying colours I have with the shading nodes. Is there a way to convert the varying colours into a texture on the sprinkles?

For the doughnut texture itself, is there a way to export the shading nodes into an image texture or something like that?

I attached images of what the 3 nodes look like, 1st one is the sprinkle geo nodes, 2nd one is the sprinkle shading nodes, 3rd one is the doughnut shading nodes.

[image: Geometry nodes for sprinkles on top the icing]

[image: Shading Nodes for sprinkles]

[image: Shading Nodes for doughnut]

Comment: There is a way to pass a numerical value from geometry nodes to the shader, and even pass color. I think it has to do with passing it to the geometry nodes group output and then taking it into the shader as an attribute.

Comment: @TheLabCat I'm sorry, how exactly do I do that? I'm still very new to blender.